# ASP.NET Disabling Page Level Cache Problems/Dangers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, cache-control, aspxgridview

Basically, the reason I am disabling the cache is because I have DevExpress ASPxGridViews, which work great for filtering, sorting, etc.  but the client is working with large amounts of data and has requested that we save the filter/sort between page navigations.

The way this is done is via an event that occurs, ClientLayout. The problem is, when the user navigates to a different page, and then clicks the browsers Back button, the events do not fire, and the unfiltered grid is displayed, presumably because this is what was cached. (However a link back to the grid's page causes the page to load properly, and the events to fire.)

The only way I have been able to solve the problem is to disable caching as pointed out in this link:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1304752/2563283.aspx

Obviously, just because I CAN do it, doesn't mean its a good idea. I understand it might affect performance a bit, but can anyone tell me of any other problems that might occur?
Maybe AJAX problems or controls giving out unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are unaware of any possible problems except for performance reduce.